# i dont know why im geting this problem FormatException (FormatException: Invalid double )

Tags: flutter, dart

when i want to  run the project

its giving me an error for the  double  telling me it is not double

main :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Homepage();
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(77, 62, 60, 60),
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 35, 34, 34),
          title: const Center(
            child: Text(
              'BMI Calculator',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: const MyTextFormField(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyTextFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTextFormField({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyTextFormField> createState() => _MyTextFormFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFormFieldState extends State<MyTextFormField> {
  final GlobalKey _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _controllerone = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllertwo = TextEditingController();
  String resulttext = '';
  double result = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Form(
              key: _formkey,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 100,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        _controllerone.text = value;
                      },
                      controller: _controllerone,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Height',
                        labelStyle:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 30,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 100,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        _controllertwo.text = value;
                      },
                      controller: _controllertwo,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        label: Text(
                          'Weight',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: calcuator(),
              child: const Text(
                'Calculate',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 60,
            ),
            Text(
              '$result',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 50,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              resulttext,
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 50,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 115,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: ContainerM.containerM(
                    heightbox: 25,
                    widthbox: 100,
                    rightnum: 0,
                    leftnum: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 42,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: ContainerM.containerM(
                    heightbox: 25,
                    widthbox: 45,
                    rightnum: 0,
                    leftnum: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 42,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: ContainerM.containerM(
                    heightbox: 25,
                    widthbox: 115,
                    rightnum: 0,
                    leftnum: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 42,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: ContainerM.containerM(
                    heightbox: 25,
                    widthbox: 90,
                    rightnum: 50,
                    leftnum: 0,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 42,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: ContainerM.containerM(
                    heightbox: 25,
                    widthbox: 60,
                    rightnum: 50,
                    leftnum: 0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  calcuator() {
    double heightnum = 0;
    double weightnum = 0;

    setState(() {
      if (_controllerone != null && _controllertwo != null) {
        heightnum = double.parse(_controllerone.text);     **************here giving me the error***
        weightnum = double.parse(_controllertwo.text);
      }
      if (heightnum <= 3) {
        heightnum = double.parse(_controllerone.text);
      } else if (heightnum > 4) {
        heightnum = double.parse(_controllerone.text) / 100;
      }
      result = weightnum / (heightnum * heightnum);
      if (result <= 18.5) {
        resulttext = 'You need to eat more';
      } else if (result >= 18.5 && result <= 24.5) {
        resulttext = 'You are healty';
      } else if (result >= 25 && result <= 29.9) {
        resulttext = 'You need to run';
      } else if (result >= 30) {
        resulttext = 'Damm bro you are so fat';
      }
    });
  }
}

class ContainerM {
  late bool right;
  late bool left;
  static containerM({
    required double heightbox,
    required double widthbox,
    required double rightnum,
    required double leftnum,
  }) {
    return Container(
      width: widthbox,
      height: heightbox,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.amber,
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
          left: Radius.circular(leftnum),
          right: Radius.circular(rightnum),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Counter {
  static counter({
    required double height,
    required double weight,
  }) {
    double res = weight / (height * height);
    return res;
  }
}
```

i tryed alot bot it didnt fix whyyyyyy ? help
the error
File : doublepatch.dart =>

```
  @patch
  static double parse(String source,
      [@deprecated double onError(String source)?]) {
    var result = _parse(source);
    if (result == null) {
      if (onError == null) throw new FormatException("Invalid double", source);
      return onError(source);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

the error in my  cods :
Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid double
)

in the * part giving me the error for the double
i think its for first the flutter going to do the mathmatik thing and then it see that the controllerone is null so i add if to it for if the controller was not null contine
but it didnt work pleas help me

Comment: can you please print out `_controllerone.text.runtimeType` and `double.parse(_controllerone.text)`. May we can see what is going wrong. :) In the your TextFormField you dont have to add onChange. The controller automatically detects the change and saves the value into controller.text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update if-else condition in `calcuator` func. Rather than null, check for empty string and also you have to check for text value.
Update your function as follow.

```
setState(() {
      if (_controllerone.text != "" && _controllertwo.text != "") {
        heightnum =
            double.parse(_controllerone.text); //here giving me the error***
        weightnum = double.parse(_controllertwo.text);

        if (heightnum <= 3) {
          heightnum = double.parse(_controllerone.text);
        } else if (heightnum > 4) {
          heightnum = double.parse(_controllerone.text) / 100;
        }
        result = weightnum / (heightnum * heightnum);
        if (result <= 18.5) {
          resulttext = 'You need to eat more';
        } else if (result >= 18.5 && result <= 24.5) {
          resulttext = 'You are healty';
        } else if (result >= 25 && result <= 29.9) {
          resulttext = 'You need to run';
        } else if (result >= 30) {
          resulttext = 'Damm bro you are so fat';
        }
      }
    });
```